# Python example for NiFi's ScriptedReader

Tags: python, apache-nifi

Can anyone provide a Python example for [ScriptedReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html)'s `Script Body` attribute? I googled and searched the NiFi's users mailing list, but was not able to find anything. There seems to be no documentation for how to use Python with this controller service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot use Jython in ScriptedReader. The reason is a Jython bug prevents you from implementing an interface that has a default method, and as of [NIFI-4004](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4004) (NiFi 1.4.0) RecordReaderFactory has a default method. There is a related case [NIFI-5995](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5995) that added documentation to that effect, and removed Jython from the list of script engines that can be used in the ScriptedLookupService component. I have written up [NIFI-7370](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7370) to cover this change for other scripted components for which their underlying interfaces have default methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of exemples for basics interaction with flowfile, attribut ... :

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but the referenced cookbook is for the ExecuteScript operator that is much more general than the ScriptedReader. So, I cannot use those recipes directly.